# ¿Como puedo hacer una validacion con mi id en ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Me encuentro con dos problemas relacionados al mismo, para ser mas breve ya tengo la solucion por aparte de cada uno.

El primero es : Agregar campo en php; El segundo: Colocar un codigo y al dar clic en otro lado, boton, espacio, etc. Mostrar en un input el nombre del codigo ingresado.

Ahora quiero combinar esos dos y no puedo... Porque me pide un ID unico ya que solo se puede de a uno, en el primero si crea el campo con el ID unico, ya solucione eso... Ahora quiero que en el segundo pueda al crear cada campo me muestre un codigo unico.

En el script de consulta.php esta mi pagina la cual debe mostrar, en este caso, funciona como ya dije el mostrar nombre por el codigo y el nombre lo pone, pero duplica el resto...

consulta.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            var contenedor      = $("#contenedor");
            var AddButton       = $("#agregarCampo");

            var x = $("#contenedor div").length + 1;
            var FieldCount = x-1;

            $(AddButton).click(function (e)
            {
                if(x)
                {
                  FieldCount++;
                  $(contenedor).append('<div class="added"><input type="text"  name="codigo[]" id="campo'+FieldCount+'" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID '+ FieldCount +'"/><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value=""></div>');
                  x++;
                }
            return false;
            });

          });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cliente">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Codigo
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="contenedor">
              <div class="added">
                <input type="text" name="codigo[]" id="codigo" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID" required/>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
      <p>
      <a id="agregarCampo" href="#">Agregar Campo</a>
      </p>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cliente.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora este es el cliente.js

```
$(function(){
   $('#cliente').on('blur','#codigo',function(){
      var valor = this.value;
      if(valor.length>=1){
         var consulta = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'cliente.php',
            data:{codigo:valor},
            dataType:'JSON'
         });

         consulta.done(function(data){
            if(data.error!==undefined){
               $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
               return false;
            } else {
               if(data.nombre!==undefined){$("#cliente #nombre").val(data.nombre);}
               return true;
            }
         });

      }
   });
});
```

Y esta es donde hace la consulta, cliente.php

```
<?php

$codigo=$_REQUEST['codigo'];
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","QWEZXCasd123","colegio");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexion)) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$registros=mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from estudiantes where estudiante_id='$_REQUEST[codigo]'") or
  die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error());

if ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{
  $return = array('nombre' => $reg['nombre_estudiante']);
} else {
  $return = array('nombre'=>'No existe el registro');
}
   die(json_encode($return));
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abajo en el siguiente codigo deberia aparecer el nombre del usuario con ese codigo.

Comment: @aldanux listo, ya cambie a $_POST, ahora... Lo hago de esta forma antes de pasarlo a MVC con PDO, la razón de hacerlo es que así logro entender como funciona y como quedara y ya luego lo implemento en un codigo mas grande... Por ahora quiero hacerlo así ya que deseo lograr su funcionamiento y ver su esqueleto, simplemente esta así por eso, pero lo de PDO es un hecho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad a necesidad de poder saber el porque no me daba mi necesidad con el ID dinamico, me vi en la necesidad de preguntarlo en el foro en ingles, hay ya respondieron mi pregunta y resolvieron la misma, aca dejo la respuesta por si a alguien mas le ocurre:

HTML/JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var contenedor = $("#contenedor");
                var AddButton = $("#agregarCampo");

                $(AddButton).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var FieldCount = contenedor.children('div').length + 1;
                    $(contenedor).append('<div class="added">\
                                            <input type="text" class="codigo_input" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID ' + FieldCount + '"/>\
                                            <input type="text" class="nombre_input" >\
                                          </div>');
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cliente">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Codigo
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="contenedor">
                            <div class="added">
                                <input type="text" class="codigo_input" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID" required/>
                                <input type="text" class="nombre_input" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <a id="agregarCampo" href="#">Agregar Campo</a>
                        </p>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#cliente').on('blur', '.codigo_input', function () {
                    var $container = $(this).closest(".added");
                    var valor = $(this).val();

                    if (valor.length >= 1) {

                        var consulta = $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'cliente.php',
                            data: {codigo: valor},
                            dataType: 'JSON'
                        });

                        consulta.done(function (data) {
                            if (data.error !== undefined) {
                                $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + data.error);
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                if (data.nombre !== undefined) {
                                    $container.find('.nombre_input').val(data.nombre);
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                        consulta.error(function(a,b,c){
                            console.log(a);
                            console.log(b);
                            console.log(c);
                        });

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y aca el PHP

```
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gabu");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from estudiantes where estudiante_id='$codigo'") or
die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));

if (mysqli_num_rows($registros) > 0) {
    $reg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros);
    $return = array('nombre' => $reg['nombre_estudiante']);
} else {
    $return = array('nombre' => 'No existe el registro');
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Un saludo, aca el link donde se soluciono por el usuario @CodeGodie

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281039/problems-with-retrieving-database-info-through-ajax-jquery-using-dynamic-fields